# Posting and retrieving Multiple Text box values using Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, post, http-post

I have Jquery code that can create multiple text boxes .Now, i want to submit my text boxes' values so that i could get them using PHP on next page.I want to submit text box in the same way as ( )
and on the second page,i could get values using POST method.How can i i post multiple text values in this case and how can i retrieve them on the next page using php?? Plz help as i am a new bee.

**CODE:**

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
        return false;
}   

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


counter++;
 });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
if(counter==1){
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
   }   
  counter--;          $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove(); });
       $("#getButtonValue").click(function ()
  {
   var msg = '';
  for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
  msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
  }

  alert(msg);
    });
    });
     </script>
    </head><body>

 <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
      <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
</div>
  </div>
  <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
  <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
  <input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'> 
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to giving name for text boxes as array
e.g. input type='textbox' name='textbox[]' id='textbox1' 
and access it on PHP page as array
$arrayRequest = $_REQUEST['textbox'];